# Accessing array via pointer in C syntax clarification

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

This is a fairly basic question that I stumbled across today and want to know the difference between two syntaxes.

Let's say I have a function that assigns a value to an array that is pointed to. I noticed that while both syntaxes compile, the second one below seg faults and the first one runs fine. Why is this?:

Works fine:

```
foo(int** arr){
    for (i = 0; i < SUM; i++){
        (*arr)[i] = i+1;
    }
}
```

Seg fault:

```
foo(int** arr){
    for (i = 0; i < SUM; i++){
        *arr[i] = i+1;
    }
}
```

Example main:

```
main(){
    int* _arr;
    arr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*50);//arbitrary
    foo(&_arr);
}
```

I wrote all this code as an example, if any clarification is needed let me know.

Comment: operator precedence between `*` and `[]`

Comment: Why are you passing and using a double pointer in the function? a single pointer: `void foo(int *arr)` is enough.

Comment: could be useful if the `malloc` is done _within_ the function. otherwise you're right, it's just food for segv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're facing operator precedence / priority issues.

- `(*arr)[i]` properly dereferences `arr` into an array, then adds `i` to get the value.
- `*arr[i]` first takes `arr+i` (uninitialized memory if `i>0`: you have only 1 array) and tries to read from that invalid pointer: segfault

Comment: After I asked this question and got to thinking more about it that seemed like the answer, but I figured I'd post anyways just to make sure. Thanks!

Comment: @TMartin To put it another way, `*arr[i]` has the same meaning as `*(arr[i])`. Sounds like you got it :)